# Making Media-Queries compatible for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, media-queries

I have had some limited success with implementing the media-queries needed for resizing of elements based on device width - however, I'm running into a snag for iDevices.

Thanks to the wonderful folks here I've been able to get my media-queries running smoothly for the iPhone 5 in landscape mode. Unfortunately, this also cuts off the media on an iPhone 4 in landscape mode. I've tried several different fixes to target the different medias (even found out that order of @media matters) but have had no such luck. One or the other gets overwritten. This is the most recent code that I have for an iPhone 4:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) {
```

And this is the code I'm using for an iPhone 5:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape) {
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look into this.  I found it a couple hours ago while fixing my media queries.  Basically it is for the iPones' super high resolution.  If I understood correctly, the new phone has basically 2pixels in the place of one.  Thus the super crisp resolution.

This meta tag sets it back the the lower resolution (if I understood correctly)
Hope it helps

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, despite not having a link to what you were referencing ;) Still nothing concrete, but its definitely helped. Thanks!